# Copy reference to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, multidimensional-array, struct

I am trying to take an array of strings (char*) and divide them equally so that a thread can manipulated it. I was thinking, theoretically, I can create a struct that points reference to a location within the filenames array.I provided a little graphic to explain it, but in the code below, what I want to do is to take every 40 filenames and insert it into the member the struct(struct array). I know it's a bit confusing, but please let me know if there's any way I can clarify it.

I would like my code to result in the array of t with references to the offseted locations within filenames, how would I go about it since in it's current state,  the compiler would not allow `t[i].files = filenames[incr];` ?

[image]

```
typedef struct divided_files{
    char** files;
    int number_of_files;
} struct_struct;

int threads = 8;
struct_struct* t = malloc(threads*sizeof(struct_struct));
char* filenames[320]; //imagine it's populated with strings

int i;
int offset = 40;
int incr = 0;
for(i = 0 ; i < threads; i++){
     t[i].files = filenames[incr];
     incr += offset;
}
```

Comment: is there a question here? What you have so far seems like it would divide up your 320 strings just fine, although you might want to set `number_of_files`. Is your concern that you don't have exactly 320 files, and you want to divide them evenly?

Comment: If the OP had posted the compiler error, it would have been more obvious... @asdasda

Comment: I made sure to clarify in a recent edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it does what you want – divide the array up, giving every thread 40 – except for a minor change. To get a pointer to an offset into an array, add the offset directly to the array pointer:

```
t[i].files = filenames + incr; // pointer arithmetic to get an offset pointer
```

Also, it looks like you're leaving `number_of_files` uninitialized; don't forget that if your code actually uses it.